# Question about series increasing and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $b_j>0$ for $j=1,$

and if $\sum_{j=1}^\infty b_j$ converges then show that

$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1+b_j}$ diverges.

My idea is that since  $b_j$ converges all the partial sums are less than a number.

But how do I show it diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:Always check the following (and its contrapositive) as a first step when solving exercises related to series of real numbers:

> Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers. If the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges then $\lim\limits_{n\to +\infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: Oh I see since the limit bj goes to zero then the limit of 1/1+bj as a j goes to infinity goes to one and thus it not convergent by zero test.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez That's right! :D